# Use an existing AngularJS directive in Angular4 application

Tags: angularjs, angular

I've got an old AngularJS directive (which I install via npm) and want to use it in my Angular4 app.

I load it like this `import * as old from 'my.old.package';`
and put it into the declarations:

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NoContentComponent,
    HighlightDirective,
    old
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS,
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-AT' }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What follows is this Error: `Unexpected value 'my.old.package' declared by the module 'AppModule'`

Comment: how do you expect it will work? Angular versions are incompatible

Comment: Apparently not, since angular/upgrade exists. I just need to get to the point where I can actually upgrade my importet AngularJS directive.